# i have a E2 error on my Bertazzoni prof304insxt range

Tags: range

prof304insxt 30-inch induction cooktop doesn't work. E2 error. I've tried resetting the power but that didn't work. How to fix or a reset inside the cooktop. oven works fine.

Comment: Have you called Bertazzoni?

Comment: yes, but they will not help and can't recommend an appliance repair company in my area.

Comment: How did you acquire this Bertazzoni prof304insxt range? I was looking at them and they are beautiful but if they are poorly supported by the company, I am not going to buy one.

Comment: my sister bought a year ago then had the cooktop replaced under warranty in august then she gave it to me. I had to rent a uhaul and pick it up in key largo. since i wasn't the one who purchased it i have no warranty. It worked for 2 months. and i live where there is no Bertazzoni repair shops. I did have an appliance repairman come out and he believe its the induction control board which he says is $800+ However, I'm not real confident that he knows for sure. I have reached out to Bertazzoni for the third time no reply as of yet. the first two times they told me where to buy parts

Comment: I rhave seen a report of someone having done a repair on the main board of another brand of induction range. Possible that this would give insight into the fault in your range.

Comment: While you are trying to figure out what to do about the Bertazzoni you could use the cooktop as a platform for countertop plug in 120 V 1800 W induction burners. One dual burner would do. Do you have a free 120 V 20 A kitchen circuit? An Empava from Lowe's is less than $300. What kind of cookware are you using? Do you do major cooking that requires 4 induction burners? Over time people will figure out how to economically repair these induction cooktops. Keep this Bertazzoni until then.

Comment: Is your Bertazzoni range hardwired or is it a NEMA 14-50 plug in? What is the breaker size on the circuit? The Bertazzoni ranges I have seen in dealer showrooms are absolutely beautiful. Try to keep this until an economical repair is available.

Comment: i did replace the plug when i brought it home and it is the nema 14-50 plug and i spoke with bertazzoni and they said that it was okay as long as i ground it a certain way which i did. And a 40 amp breaker was okay. we do have a back up cooktop burner. It did work for about 2 months no problems so i don't think it's the breaker/voltage. but you never know. I am trying to contact a local dealer that is an authorized seller to see if they can recommend a local repairman. but they are on christmas vacation. It is a beautiful unit and hope to repair with a warranty.